# What light "with no apparent material source" is Feynman referring to at the start of his Nobel lecture?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, history

Near the beginning of his 1965 Nobel lecture (end of page 2 in [this pdf](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/info/other/Feynmans_Nobel_Lecture.pdf)), Feynman justifies trying to remove the degrees of freedom of the electromagnetic field since in the end the field now is always determined by some matter earlier:

> As a matter of fact, when we look out anywhere and see light, we can always “see” some matter as the source of the light.

But right after that sentence, he mentions an exception:

> We don’t just see light (except recently some radio reception has been found with no apparent material source).

What is this radio source he talks about?

My first guess would be the observation of the CMB, which according to [wikipedia's CMB entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#History) was first observed in 1964. This same entry mentions that the interpretation was a "controversial issue", but all interpetations mentionned seem to include a matter source for the radiation, which makes me think that Feynman was maybe referring to something else.